# Principal Parts of Second Derivative of Logarithm of Gamma Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove that $\frac{d^2log\Gamma(s)}{ds^2}$ = $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}$$\frac{1}{(s+n)^2}$ holds for all complex numbers s $\neq$ 0, -1, -2, ....

How could we show it by using  infinite product representation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\Gamma(s) &= \frac{1}{s} \frac{(1+\frac{1}{n})^s}{1+\frac{s}{n}}
\\
\log \Gamma(s) &= - \log s + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[s \log(1+\frac{1}{n}) - \log(1 + \frac{s}{n})\right]
\\
(\log \Gamma)'(s) &= - \frac{1}{s} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left[\log(1+\frac{1}{n}) - \frac{1}{n+s}\right]
\\
(\log\Gamma)''(s) &= \frac{1}{s^2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(n+s)^2}
\end{align}

Comment: how can we have the first line?